# How to control the speed of a twin motor diaphragm pump electronically or electrically?

Tags: voltage, motor, power-electronics, dc-motor

I have a twin motor diaphragm pump, 12V DC 6A (might even go as high as 10A under load conditions). Picture below.

I would like a suggestion of how to be able to control its speed with a turning knob.
One more question, if we reduce its speed, would it get damaged in some way?

[image]

Would the below circuit do?
Would the 5W rating of the resistor be enough as we are dealing with 120W pump? The pot is 10K. Also I would like to restrict the pump's speed to its half speed max. What's the math and to what would it apply?

Also [this](https://www.homemade-circuits.com/dc-motor-speed-controller-circuits/) article says one needs a BJT transistor to get the full 12V to pump when full speed is required. Would a [TIP122](https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/2770/MOSPEC/TIP122.html) do?

[image]

Comment: There are too many motor/pump/load specific uncertainties to be able to be offer a definite answer. The motors MAY not like operating at hlf speed - but a semi-educated guess suggests that they are probably OK. || Half speed is probably about 70% voltage but this depends on mode of operation. Twin motor is interesting and suggests (perhaps wrongly) that the two operate in a staged sequential fashion. It MAY be that changing timings by adding a dead period may work well. || Much more detail about the pump would help. || Trying operation on a 6V battery or a variable supply would be instructive.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon I finally used a store bought module. It seems to be working fine. This pump is kind of two pumps in series. No datasheet. So lets just see how it goes. Its working fine right now.